# Parse-Server capture bad session token requests

Tags: parse-server

Is there any way to capture bad session token requests on a remote parse-server app?

Unfortunately, verbose logs for bad session tokens only display a very not verbose error message that an invalid session token was used, whereas all other requests will display the full headers used to make a request.  I need to get to those headers so I can identify the x-parse-session-token being sent.

I've discovered I can add some middleware doing something like this:

```
var myMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
  // extract request headers
  next()
}

app.use(myMiddleware)
```

But I wouldn't yet know if the session token was valid or not at that point, and I don't think it'd be efficient to set up a whole extra middleware checking the validity of every session token that gets passed in.

Any tips on how I could get access to these x-parse-session-token headers for requests that are failing due to bad session tokens would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#handling-invalid-session-token-error  review the docs for more ideas

Comment: Thanks @RobertRowntree, but unfortunately that's a client solution, not server solution. My issue stems from some very old user on a client that did not yet have the equivalent of that solution built in. I need to get a hold of this user and get them to update their app. There's some background function that is pinging my server hundreds of times a minute since it knows the server is alive and hasn't received a success callback yet...

Comment: change the userController yourself .  https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/Auth.js#L67

Comment: @RobertRowntree I was considering a solution like that as a last resort (my ideas have been getting progressively hackier haha), but since the server is built from node modules, wasn't sure how feasible it would be without restructuring it so the parse-server module was bundled with the deployment, rather than installed upon deployment. Perhaps that's an easier feat than I imagine, but it seemed infeasible and dangerous to me. I do appreciate the suggestions, though, don't mean to just brush off your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One hacky way would be to override in your middleware the `req.json` call.

```
const myMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
  const json = res.json;
  res.json = function(object) {
    if (object.code == Parse.Error.INVALID_SESSION_TOKEN) {
      // get the session token
      const token = req.headers['x-parse-session-token'];
      // Invalid token, do something
    }
    // Forward the response
    json.call(res, object);
  }
  next()
}

server = new ParseServer({
   applicationId: YOUR_APP_ID,
   /* more options */
   middleware: myMiddleware
});

// continue initialization here
```

This should do the trick what do you think?

Comment: Ahh, this looks like it would do what I need. I didn't realize I could add middleware right into the ParseServer initialization. I'll test this out locally first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes we added the middleware feature so one could do just that!